# What does a WPF DataGrid bind to the headers DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, templatebinding

When creating a WPF `DataGrid`, I have the option to set a `DataTemplate` to each column's `HeaderTemplate`, like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!-- just some random content, not important, but notice the bindings use RelativeSource-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SortFoldersByNameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Content="▲" 
                    Foreground="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsFoldersSortByName, Converter={StaticResource EnabledToBrushConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            </StackPanel>


        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Now, notice that for my bindings to work inside that template, I need to set a `RelativeSource`, because this template is not bound to the grid's `DataContext` anymore.

The question is: **what  is bound to the header's `DataTemplate`**?

If I simply try to put a `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>`, for instance, the text is empty. I don't know what other kinds of tests I could do to find out.

Comment: Do you not use Snoop Daniel? You should if you don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the datacontext is nothing.

I threw a quick template into some datagrid I have on disk.

I used this thing to answer a few questions years back.

The header isn't in the visual tree and does not inherit datacontext.

My quick and dirty header template:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="XXXX"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Examine that textblock using Snoop...

Datacontext is empty:

[image]

This is why you do all that relativesource stuff to get to your property in the datacontext.

As an aside.

If you're doing much wpf development I recommend you give Snoop a go.

It's still way better than the in built thing.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using Snoop (great tool!), you can also check that by adding a converter to the binding and inspecting it with a breakpoint. (The inspection is necessary if the binding is null, which is the case)

The `Path=.` indicates the current `DataContext`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={local:TestConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Where the converter is defined as:

```
class TestConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    //source to target
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.GetType().FullName;
    }

    //target to source
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of lazy though :^)  oh.. public.  Ah yes.  Efficient, that's the word I was thinking of.

Comment: @Andy, well... It does seem snoop is a great tool and it does sound very easy to use, but sometimes we work in a place with several rules against using third party softwares that have not been tested by the IT department (that includes using the latest visual studio and .NET framweorks as well, so even compiling the snoop codes might be something a little more complicated than just doing it.).

Comment: Fair point Daniel